# Remove Duplicate rows in left join base on one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to remove the duplicates column with the same id. I want to keep only the first one that shows up.

```
    SELECT  t.ticketId ,t.userIdOwner , t.ticketCreateDatetime , t.ticketExpectedEndDatetime , t.ticketUpdateDatetime, t.ticketUpdateBy, t.ticketLabel,t.statusTypeIdTicketState,t.statusTypeIdTicketType,t.statusTypeIdTicketModule,
    c.clientLabel, c.clientLogoOnList ,s.taskLabel , s.statusTypeIdTaskCompletion
    FROM ticket AS t
    INNER JOIN client AS c
    ON c.clientId = t.clientId
     LEFT  JOIN task AS s
    ON s.ticketId = t.ticketId  AND  s.statusTypeIdTaskCompletion = (SELECT statusTypeId FROM statusType WHERE statusTypeCode = 'waitingTask' AND statusTypeTargetTable = 'statusTypeIdTaskCompletion'  )
    
    WHERE 1=1
    AND t.ticketDeleteDatetime IS NULL
```

Here's my screen of results

[image]

Edit Image query all results

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N86S0.png)

Edit Image of task structure table  :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6apR7.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have more tasks for each ticket with same statusType

so, if you don't care about different tasks, you can simply add a `DISTINCT` clause in your `SELECT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.ticketId ,t.userIdOwner , t.ticketCreateDatetime , t.ticketExpectedEndDatetime , 
    t.ticketUpdateDatetime, t.ticketUpdateBy, t.ticketLabel,t.statusTypeIdTicketState,
    t.statusTypeIdTicketType,t.statusTypeIdTicketModule,
    c.clientLabel, c.clientLogoOnList ,s.taskLabel , s.statusTypeIdTaskCompletion
FROM ticket AS t
INNER JOIN client AS c ON c.clientId = t.clientId
LEFT  JOIN task AS s ON s.ticketId = t.ticketId  AND  s.statusTypeIdTaskCompletion = (
    SELECT statusTypeId 
    FROM statusType 
    WHERE statusTypeCode = 'waitingTask' 
    AND statusTypeTargetTable = 'statusTypeIdTaskCompletion'  
)
WHERE 1=1
AND t.ticketDeleteDatetime IS NULL
```

ok, after your edit, now we can see, that the problem is that more than one task is eligible for the ticket.

Unfortunaterly "the first that show up" is not a valid SQL statement (because the same query could give different results depending on different circumnstances).

So you have to decide wich one to keep, you need to decide a rule, a logic to keep one of the rows.

If you don't need the task label you can simply strip off that column and use the `DISTINCT`.

If you want to show a task label but don't mind which one, you can use MAX(s.taskLabel) and group by on all other columns.

If you want to keep the last task for that ticket you should provide informations about cronological order (a datetime column or an autoincrement column)

Example with `MAX(taskLabel)`:

```
SELECT 
    t.ticketId,
    t.userIdOwner, 
    t.ticketCreateDatetime, 
    t.ticketExpectedEndDatetime, 
    t.ticketUpdateDatetime, 
    t.ticketUpdateBy, 
    t.ticketLabel,
    t.statusTypeIdTicketState,
    t.statusTypeIdTicketType,
    t.statusTypeIdTicketModule,
    c.clientLabel, 
    c.clientLogoOnList,
    s.taskLabel, 
    s.statusTypeIdTaskCompletion

FROM ticket AS t
INNER JOIN client AS c ON c.clientId = t.clientId
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT s.ticketId, MAX(s.taskLabel) AS taskLabel
    FROM task AS s 
    WHERE s.statusTypeIdTaskCompletion = (
        SELECT statusTypeId 
        FROM statusType 
        WHERE statusTypeCode = 'waitingTask' 
        AND statusTypeTargetTable = 'statusTypeIdTaskCompletion'  
    )
    GROUP BY s.ticketId
) S ON s.ticketId = t.ticketId 
WHERE 1=1
AND t.ticketDeleteDatetime IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but Distinct doesn't work for me i have the same results like the first query

Comment: I even try the group by but it doesn't work at all

Comment: in your picture there are many column missing.. post the missing part so we can understand what doubles your rows. at least we should see `s.taskLabel` and `s.statusTypeIdTaskCompletion`

Comment: I updated the post so you can see the whole result just saying that the only difference in my result is column taskLabel so i must get only the first line that show up , thank you for your help sir ,

Comment: ok, as you can see, the problem is that more than one task is eligible for the ticket. now you have to decide wich one to keep. "the first that show up" is not a valid statement, because the same query could give different results dependin on different circumnstances. So you need to decide a rule, a logic to keep one of the rows.

Comment: I actually don't know how to make it so if you could help to make this logic just by keeping one ticket in the table with one task that `s.statusTypeIdTaskCompletion = 6`

Comment: do you mind which task label is shown? can you show the table structure for tasks table?

Comment: i updated the Post so you can see the task structure table  if you need any information to help me out i am here

Comment: Thank you so much , you answer work perfectly , i really appreciate your help thank you for your time sir ,